# Give information about the underlying data of the new salary calculator

Tags: feature-request, salary-calculator

Can we get some information about the data which is used by the new salary calculator to make its guess? For example the number of data points used to calculate the salary, or the age (of submission) of the data points?

This would make it easier to determine how reliable the calculated salary guess might be.